# Values at char* to number

Tags: c++, arduino

I have the following code:

```
char msg[10];
int len = acc.read(msg, sizeof(msg), 1); // This will read "R#" where # can be any number.
int number = getNumber(msg);
```

The function `getNumber` looks like this:

```
int getNumber(char* pMsg){
  Serial.println(positionMsg);
  positionMsg += 1;
  Serial.print('[');
  Serial.print(positionMsg);
  Serial.println(']');
}
```

This function prints out:

```
R115
[115]
```

When the number in the message is `115`. How do I return the integer `115`?

I come from a Java background, I don't understand pointers.

Comment: you want to translate string to integer? if so, there's [`atoi()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/)

Comment: `pMsg` or `positionMsg`? typo?

Comment: More precisely `int val; if (sscanf(msg,"R%d", &val) == 1)` you have your value in `val`.

Comment: Or [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the simplest would be to use atoi:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/

```
#include <cstdlib>  
int getNumber(char* pMsg){
    //assuming format is always R#
    return std::atoi((char*)(pMsg+1));
}
```

Or, you can use atoi directly instead of getNumber...

Comment: Might wanna adjust that pointer. Right now it is pointing to an **`'R'`**.

Comment: No problem, `std::atoi(&pMsg[1])` then.

Comment: So simple when you know how. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

Function specifies return type of int so we must return an integer. 
Using sscanf() allows you to parse/format other data types in one function call.

In C++: using sscanf()

```
    /* sscanf example */
    #include <cstdlib>

    int getNumber(char* pMsg){
        int result;
        ...
        sscanf (pMsg,"R%d",&result);  
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: sscanf is the way to go on Arduino.